# sed prevent removing rest of line

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a file containing a line which I want to replace something in the middle of it:

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://my.sql.ip.address:mySqlPort/mySqlDbName?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Assume that I want to change the IP address; I used following `sed` command:

```
sed -i -r 's/(database.url=jdbc:mysql:\/\/).+(:.+)/\1zizi/' myFile
```

This outputs:

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://zizi
```

But I want:

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://zizi:mySqlPort/mySqlDbName?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

How should I write my `sed`? Is there any other command which I can use to better get this?

Comment: Can't you just change the actual IP address with a simple sed 's/1.2.3.4/zizi/'?

Comment: @MikaelKjær, unfortunately I don't know what's inside the file before processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just print second next captured group as well `\2` (I'm not modifying or enhance your `sed`)

```
sed -i -r 's/(database.url=jdbc:mysql:\/\/).+(:.+)/\1zizi\2/' myFile
```

this is improved command to change only IP matched part.

```
sed 's/[1-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/NEWIP/' infile.txt
```

If only for the lines starts with `database.url`:

```
sed '/^database\.url/ s/[1-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/NEWIP/' infile.txt
```

Or in more `sed` capability and even shorter.

```
sed 's/\([1-9]\)\{1,3\}\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{3\}/NEW/'
```

Note that this can also can change and improve to match exact IP address rather than matching. `1.1.1.999` as a IP which is not a valid.

Answer (score 3):

Shorter ***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's~\(.*mysql://\)[^:]*~\1zizi~' file
```

The output:

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://zizi:mySqlPort/mySqlDbName?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Answer (score 0):

Short `sed` solution with no trickery:

```
$ sed 's#//[^:]*#//zizi#' file
database.url=jdbc:mysql://zizi:mySqlPort/mySqlDbName?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

This replaces everything between `//` and the immediately following `:` with the string you wanted to insert.